# I would like to see more questions about macroscopic methods here, do others agree?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

In my opinion, **Materials Modeling** covers all scales of computational modeling of materials, including mesoscopic methods such as phase-field simulations, lattice Boltzmann models, and fluid materials.

Are these on topic here?

Comment: There are several ways to address "I don't see any question related to..." but the best one by far [is this](https://materials.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @Alone Programmer: Since you had a very large number of negative votes, I attempted to "save" this question by making it sound less like a "complaint" and more like a "question". We have had a chat room going on for months now: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104555/materials-modeling-chat and you are always, ALWAYS welcome to ping me there!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree that the field of Materials Modeling covers mesoscopic methods such as phase-field simulations, lattice Boltzmann models, and fluid materials.

I would be very delighted if you wanted to ask questions from those areas!

You would be very welcome to :)